# Ошибка при сборке Native hadoop library

Tags: сборка, unix, solaris, c++, linux

Действуя согласно Build native libraries on Solaris, ввел команду

```
root@one: /export/hadoop-1.0.1/# ant -Dcompile.native=true -Dnonspace.os=SunOS -Dmake.cmd=gmake clean tar
```

и получил в результате

> BUILD FAILED
> /export/hadoop-1.0.1/build.xml:653:
> Execute failed: java.io.IOException:
> Cannot run program "gmake" (in
> directory
> "/export/hadoop-1.0.1/build/native/SunOS-x86-32"):
> error=2, No such file or directory    at
> java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
>   at
> java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>   at
> sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown
> Source)   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
>   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException:
> error=2, No such file or directory    at
> java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native
> Method)   at
> java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:79)
>   at
> java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
>   at
> java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)
>   ... 23 more
>
> Total time: 32 seconds

В результате папка build/native/platform/lib оказалась пустой.

Comment: Почти неделю уже собираете? :)

Comment: Крутой вы @ivan31 - работаете под `root` :) Точно запорете спарку

Comment: А меня другое поразило

    Total time: 32 seconds

может не стоит возиться с системой, которой надо столько времени для обнаружения ошибки в аргументах?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@ivan31](/users/4705/ivan31) я же говорил неасилишь... сделай че-нить попроще. Если говорить по сути, то:

1. Зачем вы собираете это чертов hadoop (не имею ни малейшего представления о том, что это за зверь) под платформу Solaris? Как то с трудом верится что вы сидите под Sun Sparks, если это так, то я бы на месте владельца спарки сильно бы озаботился судьбой недешевого девайса в столь ненадежных руках
2. Судя по логам где-то нет проги [GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) - он же `gmake`, подозреваю что как раз не хватает порта `gmake` для солярки

Comment: @Barmaley, вот из Википедии    
    
"Hadoop — проект фонда Apache Software Foundation, свободно распространяемый набор утилит, библиотек и программный каркас для разработки и выполнения распределённых программ, работающих на кластерах из сотен и тысяч узлов. Используется для реализации поисковых и контекстных механизмов многих высоконагруженных веб-сайтов, в том числе, для Yahoo! и Facebook."    
    
Видимо @ivan31 решил попрактиковаться с передовыми технологиями.

Comment: Я ж говорю неасилит :)

Comment: rm -rf *  - решает любую проблему с линуксом

Comment: @Barmaley , я работаю в операционной системе Nexenta illumos

Comment: @ivan31, Nexenta illumos это солярис для х86?

В чем ее ценность?